# In fragment, edittext to listview, data delivery

Tags: android, listview, tabs, fragment

> I have a project extend Fragment

Now, My project have three tabs.
it was composition fragment.

Write!!!! edittext in first tab → Push!!!! Add button → View!!!! listview in second tab

please.. help me!!

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdd);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {            
  String str = mEditMAC.getText().toString();       
   });
```

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return parent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic communication between fragments is
fragment -> activity -> another fragment

Here is sample code for callback from fragment to activity.
You can find more detail code in the http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

FirstFragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface OnBtnClickListener {
        public void buttonClicked(String mac);
    }
    OnBtnClickListener mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnBtnClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnBtnClickListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // initialize
        // ...

        final Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdd);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {            
                String str = mEditMAC.getText().toString();
                mCallback.buttonClicked(str);
            }      
        });
     }
}
```

Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements FirstFragment.OnBtnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void buttonClicked(String mac) {
        // find second fragment and call the proper function
        SecondFragment fragment = (SecondFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SecondFragment.TAG);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.buttonClicked(mac); // update second fragment's listview
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this code. but it was fail...I want to send email to you my project..may i ask your email?

Comment: I want to show error log, but my project have very many class. I was download this project file on internet. So i hard to understand this project..